# I am getting an error as invalid identifier but i couldnt find how

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE customer_details_1035
(
    cust_ID Number(5) NOT NULL,
    cust_last_name Varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    cust_mid_name Varchar2(4),
    cust_first_name Varchar2(20),
    account_no Number(5) Primary key,
    account_type Varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
    bank_branch Varchar2(25) NOT NULL,
    cust_email Varchar2(30),
)
```

This is the error I get:

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: Remove the `,` from the end of the final column's specification. SQL isn't like Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Some dialects of SQL allow (or tolerate) a comma (`,`) after the last column specification in a `create table` statement.

According to the [syntax diagrams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6), Oracle SQL doesn't allow this.

(So, the SQL parser will be looking for a column name (identifier) after the last `,`.  It finds a `)` instead ... which is not a valid identifier.)

Solution: remove the extraneous comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE customer_details_1035
(
    cust_ID Number(5) NOT NULL,
    cust_last_name Varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    cust_mid_name Varchar2(4),
    cust_first_name Varchar2(20),
    account_no Number(5) Primary key,
    account_type Varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
    bank_branch Varchar2(25) NOT NULL,
    cust_email Varchar2(30), --Remove this comma(,)
);
```